# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException editing list from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, asynchronous

I have a listView,
when I reach the position of the last visible item in the listview  I load more data (list.add(..) using an AsyncTask  ).

I need to update each activity item from another task.
What is the best way?
I tried to use iterator from main activity but I received always   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException because 2 different task are using same list.

1)

```
if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold ) {
MyTask loadMore = new MyTask(); // inside this task i do list.add(listdata);
...
}
```

2. 

```
for (Iterator<HashMap<String, Object>> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
HashMap<String, Object> item = iterator.next();
....
item.put("qt", "available");
runOnUiThread(() -> listview.invalidateViews());

}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you need to use synchronized: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/

Comment: Try to use the concurrent implementation of list type.